# Extract udf (latest version) blu-ray iso?

Tags: iso-image, 7-zip, udf

How can I extract udf blu-ray iso with fast speed? It seems like `rar` and `7z` can't read the file format. I know that you can mount it and then copy the files, but it's terribly slow for me (10MB/s on a drive with 125MB/s speed), which is also the reason why I can't use it directly (have to wait to buffer every 2-5 seconds).

Comment: Is the image perhaps residing on the same disk you’re trying to copy its contents to? Is this a HDD (“spinning rust”)?

Comment: @DanielB No. I tried copying to another disk. This is a HDD disk.

Answer (score 0):

There is only ONE valid answer:

[DVDisaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdisaster/files/dvdisaster/0.79.1/)

> Please search for a download on some trusted tech site of yours. I remember sourceforge putting unwanted stuff into their downloads.

It's Open-Source and available for Linux as for Windows. If you want, you can even create a backup of the filesystem structure. Most of times, the data might be flawless, but you don't get them displayed, because of errors in the file system.

Comment: It might be worth talking about what OSes this supports, where to find this application and how to use it

Comment: Oh sorry. I already migrated to Linux a long time, ago. For me all StackExchange sites - i use - are bout Linux. :)